# How to write a loop where the output list should be a combined list (drop the duplicates) when you pass each value of names_list in the function

Tags: python

I need some help with a problem, I'm new to the coding scene and came across this problem when working on an automation project at work. If you guys could point me out in the right direction, will really appreciate it.

If we have a list, `names = [bond, james, andy,  ......(n)]`, `n` varies every time the code runs.

`function_to_get_values(x)`, this is a function that takes one element from names, lets say `'bond'` and gives a list as output.

```
function_to_get_values('bond') = ['a', 'c', 'h']
functions_to_get_values('james') = ['c', 'r', 'f', 't', 'h']
```

How do you loop or write a code where output should look like:

```
output = ['a', 'c', 'h', 'r', 'f', 't']
```

The list should be a combined list (drop the duplicates) when you pass each value of names in the function.

So far I came up with nothing, I've been trying the loop and searching for all over the internet. Maybe I just don't know what it is called. Even if you can tell the name would really help me.

Comment: I think you might be interested in the fact that python has [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html), which might be more suited to your application than lists.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the 'a','c','h' variables/placeholders are referring to?

Comment: @nick, bond, james are group names and a, c, h are user names who are part of the group. I want to make a user list by combining all the groups.

Answer (score 1):

if the order of the element is important, do it like this:

```
def join_two_list_without_duplicates(a, b):
    r = []
    for i in a + b:
        if i not in r:
            r.append(i)
    return r
```

or you don't care the order, join the lists as following:

```
def combine_two_list(a, b):
    return list(set(a)|set(b))
```